# When to use multiple loaders in an activity or fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am trying to understand that what is loaders. Can anyone share an example with it? I don't know when we can use multiple loaders in an activity or fragment. I can't figure out one instance of multiple loaders to implement.

Comment: Check out this [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html) on the `LoaderManager` for more information... hopefully it's helpful :)

Answer (score 5):

Loaders, while commonly used to populate lists, can be used for a whole host of things. Basically, anything you to do on a separate thread can be done in a loader. If you need to make multiple calls to the network and need to do different things when you get the results, that's when you'd use multiple loaders. You could also use one loader to populate a list with a cursor, and another loader to do network calls.

Comment: So, you means that if one activity is used to list all download files, I can use multiple loaders, one loader is used to list the items, others are used to download file?

Comment: Sure, if you wanted to. Those are both "loading" operation. Althought for the file downloading, I might want to use an IntentService instead, that way even if the user exits the activity, the file will download until completion.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know when we can use multiple loaders in an activity or
>   fragment. I can't figure out one instance of multiple loaders to
>   implement.

Here you go!

**Let's suppose** you are making a news app.

You have a `ListView`/`RecyclerView` on your Launcher `Activity` which displays the news. Each of your `listItem` has one `ImageView` to display thumbnail, two `TextViews` - one for news article title & another for news article category(Ex: Politics, Sports, Technology).

Now, in order to get news, you have to fetch data from a remote server(website) using their API. And when you fetch data, that website returns data in the form of JSON.

You have to connect to that website, get the JSON, parse that JSON (i.e. extract news article title, news article category, thumbnail_URL). Then you have to download thumbnails from extracted thumbnail_URL and bind data to your `ListView`/`RecyclerView`.

In this case, you could use one `Loader` for parsing JSON; use another `Loader` to download thumbnails from extracted thumbnail_URL.